Setup AIrflow in Windows wiithout using WSL, Docker
I have tried to setup Airflow in Windows machine without using WSL or Docker for learning purpose but i'm facing the following error. so can someone help me to fix or any other alternative free methods?
tried installing using python pip
pip install apache-airflow

after that when starting server it throws this error:
airflow webserver --port 8989
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd'

when i searched this error it said its a package for linux but not for windows

The official AirFlow documentation, in the prerequisites section, says that "Airflow® currently can be run on POSIX-compliant Operating Systems" and that to install on Windows you need to use WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux 2) or via Linux Containers.
Linux and Linux Container are free alternative methods.
Another suggestion is to use a virtual machine with Linux.
